# How to exclude a website from real-time Google search results?

Tags: search, google

Google bots have recently indexed my test web site which is not intended for users.
How can i exclude my JSP web site from google's search result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a robots.txt file on the root of your server with:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

You can also add this to your start page (or any page):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
</head>
```

This should stop all indexing for crawlers who play nice.

More information at http://www.robotstxt.org/