# Robots denied by domain is still listed in search results

Tags: seo, robots.txt

So, on all of our sites that are not search facing we've applied a robots.txt file (per [How to exclude a website from real-time Google search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/how-to-exclude-a-website-from-real-time-google-search-results), or any other similar question).

However, if search terms are specific enough, the domain itself can be found via results. An example of this can be found [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=hyundai%20digital%20marketing). As you can see from the link, the domain itself can be found (content is not cached, but domain is listed). Additionally, performing a search with `site:hyundaidigitalmarketing.com` should 3 results. Checking backlinks provides a few as well, but I obviously cannot prevent them (linking is allowed in context) or control how these are handled (can't tell the host to add nofollow, noindex).

Now, I know this is a severe edge case, however my companies clients are doing just this. In fact, our domains are pretty good, so even seemingly arbitrary searches are turning up relevant results. Now, I have to write up a report on how/why this is happening.

So, I turn to the wonderful Stack Exchange network to help me either understand what I am missing or understand what is happening. Links to industry articles are extremely helpful but, anything you can give is obviously greatful. I do intend to offer bounties the best I can to make this an answer to turn to in the future.

**Edit:** I've opened a bounty on this question in hopes of getting some more responses on it. I've also provided the results of my own research below.

Answer (score 5):

I'll have to go looking for the source of this information but apparently robots.txt will not necessarily prevent a page from being indexed. But the HTTP x-robots-tag header does apparently work.

If you're using Apache you can block pages in bulk using this line in an .htaccess file:

```
Header set x-robots-tag: noindex
```

Give that a try and see what happens.

**Edit**

(Found [a source](http://bosmol.com/2009/12/robotstxt-meta-tag-versus-x-robots-tag.html). Not the one I remember but it works).

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the answer. How does this differ from the robots meta tag already implemented in the html output of the site used as an example above? As far as I can tell this just serves as a replacement so you don't need to put it on every page.

Comment: @Kevin, They *should* be the same in terms of effectiveness. This would just be easier to manage like you said.

Answer (score 4):

I think Matt Cutts talked about this. If my memory is correct it had to do with linking. 
Here is more: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=2720810fa226e9c8&hl=en

You can remove them with the Google removal tool.

Comment: You can see all of them with: site:gmpackageguide.com There are not many URL's. I assume they were in the index before the robots was disallowed. I would just remove them.

Comment: In the future, I would instruct the web design people to always include no index, no follow in the web page head section. I suspect the CMS you are using can do that.

Comment: @Joe - agree, but would recommend `noindex, follow` so that any PageRank is distributed from back-links that may occur.

Comment: @Joe & @Mike, Thanks for the information. However, take the site: hyundaidigitalmarketing.com. I launched this site myself a year ago. It includes both a robots.txt file and the meta header. However, as you can see form performing a search on google with `site:hyundaidigitalmarketing.com` or for the terms `hyundai digital marketing`, the domain itself will continue to appear as the first and best result. I need to prevent this.

Comment: Also, a search for `links:hyundaidigitalmarketing.com` shows back links. I obviously cannot prevent or control the formatting backlinks AND they might be valid. If linking to the site causes this I need to understand how/why so that I can explain this to my superiors. I hope this explains my question a bit better.

Comment: Mike, he does not want it indexed ever. Its a site for a corporate client and their dealer network. Its a closed system.

Comment: Kevin, Google is known for indexing beyond its boundaries. I saw Matt Cutts in a video where someone complained about it. He did not seem phased. The only way is to remove them with their tool. You could also do google alerts for them and when one popped up go remove it. Thats what I would do.

Comment: How would you go about the alerts? Is that something in the web dev tools?

Comment: http://www.google.com/alerts   Its wonderful.

Comment: Hey Joe, I awarded you the bounty because you provided me the initial information that helped me finalize my research. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Based on my research into the subject, I've found that there isn't a 100% guarenteed way to prevent indexing and caching of data, but you can come pretty darn close (assuming you want to deal with increased bot traffic). Here's how I've interpreted the information.

One would think that the robots.txt file is used to define robots information site-wide and meta tags are used for page specific details. I think the spirit behind the the 2 are exactly this but this is not the case in practice.

**Don't create a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file**

This works with all major search providers to prevent content from appearing on the SERP, but [does](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/search/webcrawler/slurp-04.html) [not](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35303) [prevent](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBdEwpRQRD0) indexing. This also prevents bots from crawling your pages so any robot meta tags (see below) are also ignored. Because of this you cannot use the 2 together and this is why, if you want to prevent indexing, you should not use a robots.txt file.

Side note: Google does support the use of `Noindex: /` in robots.txt, but it is undocumented (who knows when it will break) and unknown whether this works for anyone else.

**Use HTTP headers or HTML META tags to prevent everything**

Unlike the robots.txt file, the robots meta tag (and HTTP Header) is widely supported and, surprisingly, feature rich. It is designed to be set on each page, but recent adoption of the `X-Robots-Tag` header make it easy to set site-wide. The only downside with this method is that bots will crawl your site. This can be limited by using `nofollow`, but not all bots truely respect `nofollow`.

I found a ton of information in [this, outdated, blog post](http://www.antezeta.com/blog/avoid-search-engine-indexing). It's original release was 2007 but, because a lot of the information on it are newer features since then, it appears to be getting updated regularly.

In summary, you should sent an HTTP header of `X-Robots-Tag: noindex,nofollow,noodp,noydir`. Here's the break down of why:

- `nofollow` should limit the number of pages crawled on your site, keeping bot traffic down. * `noindex` tells engines to not index the page.
- Now, you might assume that `noindex` might be enough. However, I've found that even if you say `noindex` your site might be indexed because of other sites linking to it. The best way to prevent common site links from Y! Directory (`noydir`) and Open Directory (`noodp`).
- Using the HTTP header **also** applies the robots data to files, images, and other non-HTML files! YAY!

This will work in 99% of cases. Keep in mind though that it is [still possible](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/search/webcrawler/slurp-04.html) to become indexed in some cases by some providers. Google claims to fully respect `noindex`, but I have my suspicions.

Finally, if you do get indexed, or have already been indexed, the only way to get your information de-indexed is to follow the various means from each provider to request the site/url be removed. Obviously this means that you will probably want to monitor the sites/pages using something like [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) (thanks @Joe).

Answer (score 3):

I think your basic issue is the back links to the site as these give the search engines an entry point to the site and make them aware of it. So although they will not display a description for the site they may show the URL if they think its the best match for the result.

Have a read of this article linked to from the one @joe posted: [Matt Cutts keeping google out](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/googlebot-keep-out/)

The key bit is:

> There’s a pretty good reason for that: back when I started at Google in 2000, several useful websites (eBay, the New York Times, the California DMV) had robots.txt files that forbade any page fetches whatsoever. Now I ask you, what are we supposed to return as a search result when someone does the query [california dmv]? We’d look pretty sad if we didn’t return www.dmv.ca.gov as the first result. But remember: we weren’t allowed to fetch pages from www.dmv.ca.gov at that point. The solution was to show the uncrawled link when we had a high level of confidence that it was the correct link. Sometimes we could even pull a description from the Open Directory Project, so that we could give a lot of info to users even without fetching the page.

The research you have done also covers things quiet well and the answers by @john and @joe are both relevant. I have included a link below which gives some further guidance on blocking search engines. The only way i can think to completely block the site would be to add some form of password protection in front of the site that needs to be completed before the content is displayed.

[SEOMoz tips on not appearing in search](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/12-ways-to-keep-your-content-hidden-from-the-search-engines)

Comment: Thanks for adding to the discussion. Password protection works well to prevent crawling, but doesn't prevent indexing. Since the robots.txt does a good job at stoping this the only advantage to password protection is that it will prevent prying eyes from finding it. Unfortunately, most content isn't sensitive enough to be "protected" and certainly doesn't warrent the usability issues it creates. [cont...]

Comment: One analogy I found most helpful in my research was a comparison to to phone books. If search engines are phone books, and you ask not to be listed, then you can ask to not be listed, ever, and they should respect that. Unfortunately, search engines are acting more similar to the companies that other companies sell contacts to which is in turn given to anyone willing to pay/ask for it.

Comment: @Kevin i understand what you are saying unfortunately i don't think its going to be possible to be completely removed with the way search engines work at present the best you can hope for is just a URL listing in that case.

Comment: Oh, I understand that now (post-research). Also, please don't take my comment to your answer in any negative light. I appriciate your addition to the topic, I was simply replying to add in the cons of implementing such a solution, plus adding a little off-topic banter I suppose. :P