# How to hide my website from search engines using robots.txt?

Tags: search-engines, robots.txt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Robots denied by domain is still listed in search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11700/robots-denied-by-domain-is-still-listed-in-search-results)

I want to hide my website from all search engines for that i write robots.txt in that robots.txt i write code as

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But still my website is in serchable why?

Answer (score 1):

Although the `robots.txt` file the *standard* way to signify to search engines which areas of your sites you would like indexed and which you wouldn't, it doesn't *have* to be followed.

In the case of the big players, Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc, they do follow the rules.. but some of the smaller players may not and so you may appear in their indexes.

Also, if your `robots.txt` change is recent a search engine may take time to purge your site from their index.