# How to force search engines not to crawl my site, is there any special mark on them?

Tags: search-engines, web-crawlers

I want to block search engines from crawling my websites. Atleast for Msn, Yahoo, Google, and Yandex.

i dont really trust robot.txt. Because they can simply ignore it and continue crawling.

I would use rails as my web framework.

How can i do it, atleast to decrease the posibility destructive action they do by simply crawling a specific page.

Is there any special mark or identifier on them while they are crawling a site ?

This question marked as duplicate with
[Robots denied by domain is still listed in search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11700/robots-denied-by-domain-is-still-listed-in-search-results)

Wich is i guess a mistake. Above questions is asking specifically why. I dont really care why google crawling my site. I just want to block it. Show 404 status.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to specify search engine crawling instructions for non-html files without having to use `robots.txt`. This comes first in listing. Some other crawling control methods listed below:

Use `noindex`page meta tags:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

Use `index` in page meta tags with searchengine name to crawl:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="index" />
```

**Nofollow:** Tell search engines not to spider some or all links on a page

```
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />
```

*To specify nofollow at the link level, add the attribute rel with the value nofollow to the link:*

```
<a href="mypage.html" rel="nofollow" />
```

Use `X-Robots-Tag` in your http headers which is accepted only by yahoo.

Comment: Resource: http://antezeta.com/news/avoid-search-engine-indexing